# Ways to share data among NativeScript mobile applications

Tags: nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript-angular, mobile-development, nativescript-plugin

We have few different enterprise mobile applications being built with NativeScript. Are there any NativeScript plugins that can be used to share data among those apps. 
For example: 
  1) App1 might store some JSON 
  2) App2, App3 would be able to retrieve the stored JSON upon their open.

Thank you,
Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS you have to enable `App Groups` capability for your app ids and write your files to the [app group container](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412643-containerurlforsecurityapplicati?language=objc).

For Android you have to implement [ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), of course all of these require bit of native coding.

Comment: Thank you Manoj. Is following the typical workflow in using AppGroups in iOS..?

1) App1 has AppId 'org.ficcomp.app1', App2 has an AppId of 'org.ficcomp.app2'. 
2) Enable 'App groups' feature for both AppIds in apple developer console.
3) Add same 'App group' in xcode capabilities of both apps. 
         For Example: org.ficcomp.paapps.group
4) Use native code to store data into the group container.